# React - conditional/message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I have the following code and need to add two extra things to it but I'm stuck and not sure how to do it.

I need to add:

- If there are no products in the category a NotFound component will show a message.
- By typing 'all' in the input we should be able to see the entire list of products again from all the categories.

Ideally I'm looking for the simplest solution as I'm currently learning React. Thanks!

**Main Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import Item from './components/Item';

class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    items: [
      {
        title: "The Spice Girls",
        price: 10,
        category: "Pop",
        quantity: 1,
      },
      { 
        title: "Beethoven",
        price: 5,
        category: "Classical", 
        quantity: 1,
      },
      {
        title: "Bob Marley",
        price: 15,
        category: "Reggae",
        quantity: 1,
      }
    ],
    category: " ",
    filtered: [],  
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({category: e.target.value},()=>console.log(this.state.category));
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()

    var newList = this.state.items;
    var filteredItems = newList.filter(item => item.category === this.state.category)
    this.setState({filtered: filteredItems})
  }

  render () {
    let show;

    if(this.state.category !== " "){
    show = this.state.filtered.map((item, i) => <Item key = {i} cd={item}/>)
        
    }else{
    show = this.state.items.map( (item,i) => <Item key = {i} cd={item}/>)
   }


    return (
      <div>
        <h1 className = "title">CD</h1>
        <h2>Search music below:</h2>
        <form>
            Music style: <input onChange = {this.handleChange}></input>
            <button onClick = {this.handleClick}>Search</button>
         </form>
        {show}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Item Component**

```
import React from 'react';

class Item extends React.Component {

    render () {
        return (
            <div className = "items"> 
                 <div className = "item">
                    <h3>{this.props.cd.title}</h3>                    
                    <div className = "price">Price: {this.props.cd.price}€</div>
                    <div className = "quantity">Quantity: {this.props.cd.quantity}</div>
                    <div className = "category">Category: {this.props.cd.category}</div>
                  </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}  
 
export default Item;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First of all some suggested changes before I answer your question

There are a few things which confused me much when analysing your code, so will share them with you, as if in the future you work on teams, it would be handy if other people can understand your code.

- You have an on change event for the text box which is different to the event for the search button next to it. Users would expect it to be the same and so that's really confusing.
- You have 2 lists of items essentially, a raw and unfiltered and you switch between which 2 to present on the screen. Sometimes you need to have a raw set and that's fine, but perhaps make sure that the only ones which are `presented as such` is just either the `state.items` or the `state.filtered`. I would probably expect the `state.filtered`
- Make your search case insensitive, e.g. pop should match Pop

## Answer to your question'ss

> If there are no products in the category a NotFound component will show a message.

For this I would first modify your show logic to work on the same filtered list just change your event functions to manipulate the filtered list and untouch the items one.

add another condition perhaps for when there are no cases

```
   if (this.state.filtered) {
      show = this.state.filtered.map((item, i) => <Item key={i} cd={item} />);
    } else {
      show = <h1>NoneFound</h1>;
    }
```

> By typing 'all' in the input we should be able to see the entire list of products again from all the categories.

```
handleClick = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    var { category } = this.state;
    var newList = this.state.items;

    var filteredItems;
    if ([" ", "All"].some(t => t === category)) {
      filteredItems = newList;
    } else {
      filteredItems = newList.filter(
        item => item.category.toLowerCase() === this.state.category.toLowerCase()
      );
    }
    this.setState({ filtered: filteredItems });
  };
```

My souloution to this was to modify your onClick event to correctly manipulated the filtered list.

You can see my full soloution to this on my codesandbox here

[image: Edit Autocomplete]

Comment: Thanks so much! I have a couple of questions; what does the 't' mean in this line: if ([" ", "All"].some(t => t === category)) {

Comment: basically is a lambda or anonymous function. Together its a shorthand way of saying if any of the categories are equal to " " or "All". The some function will iterate over " " and "All" (like a loop) and compare each one (t) to the category, and if any of them match it returns true. Some similar functions are map, filter, find and every. You can read about them here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some Because its an anonymous function you can call "t" what you like, its usually conventional to have it extremely short. I used t for "term"

Comment: it could also be written like this if [" ", "All"].some( function(term) { if term === caterory return} or we could extract this function out entirely like this `const someExpression = t => t=== category` then we could do `[" ", "All"].some(someExpression)`

Comment: @Cristina, If my answer helped you could you mark the answer as accepted or vote it up This will give me points 

Comment: Great! :) I understand now! I'm having a couple of problems though, the NoneFound doesn't seem to work. If I add another category and don't add products to it, the name of the category shows, instead of saying NoneFound (this ideally should be a separate component). I also need to initally display all of the products on the page before searching but if I use your solution, the products are initially hidden.

Comment: Ahh, i see I made a mistake. I have updated the sandbox, there ive changed `if (this.state.filtered) { ` to `if (this.state.filtered?.length) {` since it was always initiated then it was always true, where as now its only true if its got a length > 0

Comment: Yes I added the name of the category typed in just for debgging, you can remove that bit if you dont need it

Comment: I have updated the sandbox so that NoneFound is its own component